# Void-type not allowed here error

Tags: java, list, treemap

I am trying to add these data I have read from a file into my map. My map is a treemap `TreeMap<String, Student>`, where Student in another class. I am trying to use the code `map.put(formatSNumber, student.setCourses(courses));` to add the read file elements to my map, but I keep encountering that void type not allowed here error.

```
sNumber = Integer.parseInt(Breader.readLine());
formatSNumber = String.format("%03d", sNumber);
hours = Integer.parseInt(Breader.readLine());
grade = Double.parseDouble(Breader.readLine());
Student student = map.get(formatSNumber);
Course course = new Course(hours, grade);
List<Course> courses = student.getCourses();
courses.add(course);
map.put(formatSNumber, student.setCourses(courses));
end = Breader.ready();
```

Here is my full code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
public class FinalProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String nameFile = " ";
        String classFile = " ";
        TreeMap<String, Student> map = new TreeMap<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            System.out.print("Enter the Name file(c:filename.txt): ");
            nameFile = input.nextLine();
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.printf("Invalid input. Please enter"
                    + " filename in the form of "
                    + "c:filename.txt\n", e.getMessage());
        }
        nameReader(nameFile, map);

        try {
            System.out.print("Enter the Class file(c:filename.txt): ");
            classFile = input.nextLine();
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.printf("Invalid input. Please enter"
                    + " filename in the form of "
                    + "c:filename.txt\n", e.getMessage());
        }
        classReader(classFile, map);
    }

    private static void nameReader(String file, TreeMap<String, Student> map)
            throws IOException {

        String nameFile = file;
        int sNumber = 0;
        String formatSNumber = " ";
        String sName = " ";

        //Instantiate FileReader and BufferedReader
        FileReader freader = new FileReader(nameFile);
        BufferedReader Breader = new BufferedReader(freader);
        boolean end = Breader.ready();

        do {
            sNumber = Integer.parseInt(Breader.readLine());
            formatSNumber = String.format("%03d", sNumber);
            sName = Breader.readLine();
            Student student = new Student(sName);
            map.put(formatSNumber, student);
            end = Breader.ready();
        } while(end);
        Iterator<String> keySetIterator = map.keySet().iterator();
        while(keySetIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = keySetIterator.next();
            System.out.println("key: " + key + " value: " + map.get(key).getName());
        }
    }
    private static void classReader(String file, TreeMap<String, Student> map) 
            throws IOException {
        String classFile = file;
        int sNumber = 0;
        String formatSNumber = " ";
        int hours = 0;
        double grade = 0.0;
        double points = grade * hours;
        double GPA = points / hours;

        //Instantiate FileReader and BufferedReader
        FileReader freader = new FileReader(classFile);
        BufferedReader Breader = new BufferedReader(freader);
        boolean end = Breader.ready();

        do {
            sNumber = Integer.parseInt(Breader.readLine());
            formatSNumber = String.format("%03d", sNumber);
            hours = Integer.parseInt(Breader.readLine());
            grade = Double.parseDouble(Breader.readLine());
            Student student = map.get(formatSNumber);
            Course course = new Course(hours, grade);
            List<Course> courses = student.getCourses();
            courses.add(course);
            map.put(formatSNumber, student.setCourses(courses));
            end = Breader.ready();
        } while(end);

        points = grade * hours;
        GPA = points / hours;
    }
}
```

Student class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Student {
    private String name = " ";
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Student(String name, List courses) {
        this.name = name;
        this.courses = courses;
    }
    public List getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }
    public void setCourses(List courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Course class:

```
public class Course {
    private int hours = 0;
    private double grade = 0.0;
    public Course(int hours, double grade) {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    public void setHours(int hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }
    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }
    public void setGrade(double grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    public double getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }
}
```

Comment: student.getCourses(courses) has a return type of List<Courses>. The map, however, wants a student as a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of **put** is about **putting** *something* into that Map.

More precisely, you typically provide (non-null) key and a value objects.

You are using `student.setCourses(courses)` as argument for that "value" parameter that `put()` expects.

That argument is an **expression**. And the result of that expression would be the result of the **method call**.

That method is defined to **not return** anything (void that is).

Obviously *nothing* is not the same as *something*. And that is what the compiler tries to tell you.

Two solutions:

1. pass a Student object
2. change that method setCourses()

Like this:

```
Student setCourses(... {
....
  return this;
}
```

( you better go for option 1; 2 is more of a dirty hack, bad practice in essence )

Answer (score 3):

The second argument in `map.put(formatSNumber, student.setCourses(courses))` must be of type Student. `student.setCourses(courses)` is a setter method with return type void, i.e. no return. This does not match.

You must have something like `map.put("someString", new Student("name"))` for instance, or `map.put("someString", student)` where `student` is of type `Student`.

Comment: Ok. I am feeling a bit overwhelmed here. I am trying to add my `Course` object to the `Student` objects collection of courses, and I am lost in the syntax here.

Comment: I am not sure if that is what you want, but try: List<Course> courses = student.getCourses();
courses.add(course);
map.put(formatSNumber, student); You could also do: student.getCourses().add(course); map.put(formatSNumber, student). It is the same.

Comment: How can I go deep into the map and access `student`?

I want to go into the map like this:

Pull up the studentID(formatSNumber), and then, show the corresponding `student` object's courses.